Why is the negative exponential part ignored in phasor representation of sinusoidal voltage source?
Given a sinusoidal voltage source in the form:
$$ u(t) = \hat{U} \cdot \sin(\omega\cdot t+\phi_u) $$
\$u(t)\$ can be converted to its complex exponential form using Euler's formula:
$$ \sin(\alpha)=\frac{1}{2\cdot j}\cdot \{ \exp{(j\cdot \alpha)} - \exp{(-j\cdot \alpha})\} $$
Thus:
$$ u(t) = \hat{U} \cdot  \frac{1}{2\cdot j} \cdot \{  \exp{(j \cdot [\omega\cdot t+\phi_u])} - \exp{(-j\cdot [\omega\cdot t+\phi_u}])\} $$
However, in many textbooks and exercises, I often see that only the positive exponential part is used for the phasor representation:
$$ \underline{U} = \hat{U} \cdot  \exp{(j \cdot \phi_u)} $$
Why is this the case? Why is the negative exponential part ignored when representing the phasor? Additionally, the frequency \$\omega\$ is not explicitly included in the phasor representation.

You mean ALL textbooks
If you keep both exponentials the imaginary parts will cancel at the end.
Using one exponential and taking the real part at the end is fast and efficient.

Hello and thx for reply. What do you mean exactly by „If you keep both exponentials the imaginary parts will cancel at the end.“? You mean at the end of analysing a ac circuit? For instance calculating the voltage $v_L(t)$ across an inductivity $ L $ in a $RL$-series circuit supplied by the given current source $i(t)$? So the result then consist only of a real part?

An example can be useful in order to get a valuable insight about phasors. Consider the following RLC series circuit:

and a sinusoidal excitation:
$$ v(t)=V_p\cos(\omega t+\theta_v)=\text{Re}\left\{\mathbf{V}e^{j\omega t} 
\right\}  \qquad [1]$$
where \$\text{Re{}}\$ gets the real part from its complex argument; with \$V_p\$ and \$\theta_v\$ being the peak voltage value and phase shift, respectively. Also:
$$ \mathbf{V}=V_pe^{j\theta_v} \qquad [2]$$
Pay attention in \$[2]\$: \$\mathbf{V}\$ is called a phasor associated to \$v(t)\$. This is a complex quantity independent of time \$t\$ and frequency \$\omega\$.
The application of KVL results in a linear differential equation, as below (\$v_C\$ is the capacitor voltage):
$$L\frac{di(t)}{dt}+Ri(t)+v_C(t)=v(t) $$
Deriving wrt time:
$$L\frac{d^2i(t)}{dt^2}+R\frac{di(t)}{dt}+\frac{dv_C(t)}{dt}=\frac{dv(t)}{dt}$$
Replacing \$\frac{dv_C(t)}{dt}=\frac{i(t)}{C}\$
$$L\frac{d^2i(t)}{dt^2}+R\frac{di(t)}{dt}+\frac{1}{C}i(t)=\frac{dv(t)}{dt} \qquad [3]$$
Note: From now, I'm interested on the Forced Response. This is the response which does not involve the natural modes of the system, also called Particular Solution.
As \$[3]\$ is linear, it can be assumed a solution \$i(t)\$, similar to \$[1]\$ in form, or:
$$ i(t)=I_p\cos(\omega t+\theta_i)=\text{Re}\left\{\mathbf{I}e^{j\omega t} 
\right\}  \qquad [4]$$
With
$$ \mathbf{I}=I_pe^{j\theta_i} \qquad [5]$$
This is a phasor associated to \$i(t)\$, where \$I_p\$ is the peak current value and \$\theta_i\$ is corresponding phase shift.
Replacing \$[1]\$ and \$[4]\$ in \$[3]\$:
$$ L\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\text{Re}\left\{\mathbf{I}e^{j\omega t} 
\right\}+R\frac{d}{dt}\text{Re}\left\{\mathbf{I}e^{j\omega t} 
\right\}+\frac{1}{C}\text{Re}\left\{\mathbf{I}e^{j\omega t} 
\right\}= \frac{d}{dt}\text{Re}\left\{\mathbf{V}e^{j\omega t} 
\right\}$$
Taking the derivatives wrt and remembering that \$\mathbf{I}\$ and \$\mathbf{V}\$ are independent of time:
$$ L\space \text{Re} \left \{(j\omega)^2\mathbf{I}e^{j\omega t} \right \} + R\space \text{Re} \left \{j\omega\mathbf{I}e^{j\omega t} \right \}+\frac{1}{C}\space \text{Re} \left \{\mathbf{I}e^{j\omega t} \right \}=\text{Re} \left \{ j\omega\mathbf{V}e^{j\omega t} \right \}$$
Using the linearity property:
$$ \text{Re}\left\{ \left [L(j\omega)^2 + Rj\omega + \frac{1}{C} \right ]\mathbf{I}e^{j\omega t} \right \} = \text{Re}\left \{ j\omega \mathbf{V}e^{j\omega t} \right \} $$
Using the uniqueness property:
$$ \left [L(j\omega)^2 + Rj\omega + \frac{1}{C} \right ]\mathbf{I}e^{j\omega t} = j\omega \mathbf{V}e^{j\omega t} $$
Finally:
$$ \mathbf{I} =\frac{\mathbf{V}}{j\omega L + R + \frac{1}{j\omega C}} \qquad [6]$$
This is a classical expression for the current phasor \$\mathbf{I}\$, given the voltage phasor \$\mathbf{V}\$ and the impedance \$\mathbf{Z}\$:
$$ \mathbf{Z}= j\omega L + R + \frac{1}{j\omega C}$$
or
$$ \mathbf{Z}= j\omega L + R -j \frac{1}{\omega C}$$
Other circuits configurations can be treated in a similar manner, as well.
Conclusion: Here, we don't need the "negative exponential", which you refer to, because the phasor is not working in the time domain (also, as already said, the phasor is independent of time). Note that, an alternative development could be done, for example, using:
$$ v(t)=V_p\sin(\omega t+\theta_v)=\text{Im}\left\{\mathbf{V}e^{j\omega t} 
\right\} $$
where \$\text{Im{}}\$ gets the imaginary part from its complex argument.
In summary: The phasor concept is just a math artifact, or a transform to frequency domain, useful for simplification (thanks to Mr. Charles Proteus Steinmetz), when solving circuits with sinusoidal excitation in steady state. So, is enough to deal with peak values and time shifts, since the frequency \$\omega\$ appears explicitly in the impedance calculation. Always is possible to "return" to time domain, using the \$\text{Re}\{\}\$ operator (see \$[1]\$ and \$[4]\$). The concept can generalized to non sinusoidal inputs, resulting in Fourier and Laplace transforms. On Time: A general signal can be decomposed in an infinite sum of infinitesimally weighted complex exponentials.

Good you mention Charles Proteus Steinmetz, for whom the unit of frequency (cps) was named.

@richard1941 Yes, this is a very interesting fact in EE history.

Phasor analysis does not represent a sine as a sum of two complex exponentials. It's doing something more subtle -- taking advantage of linearity.
Let's say you have a circuit with a voltage source \$v_s\$, and that source produces a node voltage \$v_n\$ elsewhere in the circuit:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In this case, \$v_n = v_s / 2\$. Now, linearity says that if you multiply \$v_s\$ by a constant (let's say 5), then \$v_n\$ increases by the same amount -- \$v_n = 5v_s / 2\$. Mathematically, we can also multiply the voltage by i, the imaginary unit:
$$v_n = iv_s/2$$
The key point is that if we make our voltage source imaginary, all of the node voltages in our circuit will be imaginary too!
Linearity also says that if you replace \$v_s\$ with two sources, the response is now the sum of those sources:
$$v_n = (v_{s1} + v_{s2})/2$$
But what if one of our sources is real and one is imaginary?
$$v_n = (v_{s1} + iv_{s2})/2$$
Our node voltage is now a complex number. Its real part is entirely due to \$v_{s1}\$ and its imaginary part is entirely due to \$v_{s2}\$. This is phasor analysis. We take an existing voltage source, like:
$$v_s(t) = 10\cos(\omega t)$$
We replace it with two voltage sources, one of which is imaginary:
$$v_s(t) = 10\cos(\omega t) + j10\cos(\omega t)$$
These sources product a complex response:
$$v_n(t) = (10\cos(\omega t + \phi) + j10\cos(\omega t))/2$$
The real part of the response is entirely due to the real part of the source. So if we drop the imaginary part of the response, it's just like we never added the imaginary source at all:
$$v_n(t) = 10\cos(\omega t)/2$$
Adding the imaginary source doesn't change our real answer, but it does let us treat the voltages as complex exponentials, which makes the math easier:
$$v_s(t) = \mathrm{Re}\{10e^{j\omega t}\}$$
$$v_n(t) = \mathrm{Re}\{10e^{j\omega t}/2\}$$

Hello Adam, your explanation is really good. thx a lot. do you have a book recommendations where I can read some sections about that topic? thx and best regards

We used the Hayt and Kemmerly circuit analysis textbook in college, which I thought was pretty good.

Circuit behavior is described by linear differential equations. The general solution to such equations is the complex exponential.
Specific solutions can be formed via linear combinations of the general solution. You can have any linear combination you want: a sum of a positive complex exponential and a negative one, or you can leave out the negative one. Both are solutions.
A very common specific solution is the one that yields a real sinusoid because it is convenient to plot with 2D axes.

Here is a thoughtful explanation:
https://engineering.purdue.edu/wcchew/ece604f20/Lecture%20Notes/Lect6.pdf
starting with:

it's worth reading Chew's lecture above.
